# How to get JSON response from Spring Controller to JQueryAjax?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

How to get json response from Spring Controller to JQueryAjax,
I am trying to get json data from Controller but getting error ststus in JQueryAjax,
Have any error in my code this is a simple login application
    This is my Controller in Spring

```
HomeController.java

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User loginUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, User ub)
    {

        String email = request.getParameter("txt_email");
        String password = request.getParameter("txt_password");

        ub.setEmail(email);
        ub.setPassword(password);

        UserServiceImpl us = new UserServiceImpl();
        User ub1=new User();
        ub1= us.verifyUserLogin(ub);

        return ub1;
    }
```

This is my JQueryAjax

data.js

```
    function usersignin(url)
    {
        var val = signin_validate();
        if (val == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        var email = $('#txt_email').val();
        var password = $('#txt_password').val();
        var formData =
        {
                'txt_email' : email,
                'txt_password' : password,

        };
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : url,
                    data : formData,
                    dataType: "json",

                    success : function(res, textStatus)
                    {
                        var msg="Succesfully..! Login";
                        showAlertLogin(msg);
                        window.location.href='index.jsp'            

                    },

                    error : function(res, textStatus)
                    {
                        var msg="Failed..! Login";
                        showAlertLogin(msg);
                        window.location.href='layout.jsp'           

                    }
                });

    }
```

I added dependency file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

But i didnt get json response in ajax only getting error why?
One error in console is

[http-nio-8080-exec-5] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: Please try dataType : 'Json' in ajax calling.

Comment: @NikhilGupta I added but not working

Comment: @Nikhil I added in my js but not working

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **Spring 3.1**, a the **@RequestMapping** annotation now has a **produces**  specifically for this purpose:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User loginUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, User ub)
    {

        String email = request.getParameter("txt_email");
        String password = request.getParameter("txt_password");

        ub.setEmail(email);
        ub.setPassword(password);

        UserServiceImpl us = new UserServiceImpl();
        User ub1=new User();
        ub1= us.verifyUserLogin(ub);

        return ub1;
    }
```

Add Dependency:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[References:spring-3-mvc-and-json-example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)

Comment: Igot error in Jquery and error in console too the error is this one [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: you have jar dependency problems

Comment: I mention my dependency in my question.Please help me.Without Json data its work fine?

Comment: I am using  Spring 4.2.2.RELEASE i added entire dependency file

Comment: have you added **<mvc:annotation-driven />** ?

Comment: Yes i added **<mvc:annotation-driven />**

Comment: 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd'

Comment: Could you share **User** class?

Comment: **User** must contain public getters for its properties.

Comment: Yes I have private declartion and public getter and setter

Comment: igot this error in my console [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: try adding **com.fasterxml.jackson** dependencies.

Comment: I added dataType:'json'  in my JQuery for recieving json then i  enable <mvc annotation in my dispatcher servlet then i add 'produces = "application/json" ' then i add all dependency guide by you  and share bean too but not getting json data .Previous error in my console

Comment: please give me your mail id